# GNU Make: split file (serial), then work on parts (parallel)

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want to do a calculation based on two data files. The calculcation is memory-heavy, so I cannot do them all at once. I split the job into 200 pieces, and then run the calculation on the pieces, which are later combined.
I automated this in a Makefile:

```
.PHONY: SPLITS QOAC
.SECONDARY: QOAC SPLITS

NSETS = 200
DSETS := $(patsubst %,cache/split_%.rds,$(shell seq 1 1 $(NSETS)))
QSETS := $(patsubst %,cache/qoac_%.rds,$(shell seq 1 1 $(NSETS)))

QOAC: $(QSETS)
SPLITS: $(DSETS)

$(DSETS): split_files.R data/1 data/2
    Rscript $< $(NSETS)

cache/qoac_%.rds: calc_qoac.R cache/split_%.rds
    Rscript $^

bigfile: combine.R QOAC
    Rscript $<
```

In this example, `NSETS` pieces are generated by `split_files.R`, which reads `data/1` and `data/2`. The sets are saved in `cache/split_*.rds`.
For every `split_*`, `qoac_*` is computed using `calc_qoac.R`. As these processes are isolated, they can be run in parallel by running `make -j`.
My problem is that if 1(+) of the `split_*` is missing, `split_files.R` is run multiple times.

When I add `.NOTPARALLEL: SPLITS`, the entire script is run serially, which slowes things down.

How can I make sure the generation of the sets is done only once when needed?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working by following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47951465/2485807).
It made me use a `PHONY` target. I thought I already did this, with `SPLITS` and `QOAC`, but now I solved it like this:

```
cache/split_%.rds: SPLITS

SPLITS: split_files_qoac.R data/INR_data.rds data/patient_data.rds
    Rscript $< $(NSETS)

cache/qoac_%.rds: calc_qoac.R cache/split_%.rds
    Rscript $^
```